# Hiding rows using a macro

Tags: excel

I've got this project I'm working on where I have a "Data" sheet and am pulling the data in to "Sheet 2". I want a row on "Sheet 2" to automatically hide/unhide if there is no data within a specific cell in that row.

I am very new to macros and coding in general. I have tried looking this up but and following the tutorials on YouTube but none of them go too in-depth as to why you select certain things and I haven't had any luck getting them to work.

My question are.:

1. Would a macro that is effecting "Sheet 2" while I am on "Data", be placed within "Sheet 2" or within "ThisWorkbook"?
2. Before you write the macro, you need to select the drop downs "Workbook" and then I would assume you are detecting a change so would "SheetChange" be correct?
3. Will a macro detect a change within a cell that is hidden and then can that cell's row be unhidden?
4. Lastly, What the heck do I even write for the to detect a 0 and hide/unhide cells, I haven't gotten any of them to do anything so far?

Thank you for any help you guys can give.

Comment: I'm assuming Sheet 2 pulls in the data via a formula?

Comment: "I haven't gotten any of them to do anything so far?" -- Can you edit your question to post the code you do have?

Comment: For most of your code that does NOT deal with specific actions (events) on your worksheet, create a new Module to put your code to start with, not in the Sheet1 or ThisWorkbook modules. Right-click on the module tree in the VBA Editor and select Insert->Module. If you were to use the `SheetChange` event, that goes in the specific worksheet module in which you want to catch the event. You can check for hidden cells in the code, look at [this link](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2004/10/22/determine-if-cell-is-hidden-in-vba/)

Comment: @PeterT I think OP meant [`Workbook.SheetChange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.sheetchange) event, but in any case I'm thinking this might be a case for the [`Worksheet.Calculate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.calculate(even)) event. We'll see...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your questions:

> 1. Would a macro that is effecting "Sheet 2" while I am on "Data", be placed within "Sheet 2" or within "ThisWorkbook"?

It doesn't matter where you place the code unless the code is triggered by a built in event like Worksheet_Change(). In that case then it must reside within the worksheet that you are wanting to detect changes in. If it's not event driven then I would place the code in it's own module. To each their own though.

> 2. Before you write the macro, you need to select the drop downs "Workbook" and then I would assume you are detecting a change so would "SheetChange" be correct?

It would be appropriate if you wanted the code contained in that subroutine to be executed whenever there is a change to that worksheet. You could also trigger code through a user action like a button click or a double click or sheet activation, etc.

> 3. Will a macro detect a change within a cell that is hidden and then can that cell's row be unhidden?

Sure! Why not? As an example:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    'Detect if the change was in a cell we care about (it can be hidden, VBA don't care)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Column(3)) Is Nothing Then
        'Something changed in Column C! Unhide whatever row had the change
        Target.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If

End Sub
```

> 4. Lastly, What the heck do I even write for the to detect a 0 and hide/unhide cells, I haven't gotten any of them to do anything so far?

Using that last example to detect if a particular column experienced a change, detect if it was just a single cell, detect if that single cell is now a `0` and hide it's row:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    'Detect if the change was in a cell we care about (it can be hidden, VBA don't care)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Column(3)) Is Nothing Then
        'Something changed in Column C!
        If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
            If Target.Value = "0" Then
                Target.EntireRow.Hidden = True
            End If
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Stick that in whatever worksheet you wanting to detect the change. Change that first `If` so that you are only detecting changes in whatever range you anticipate that change to happen in (I chose Column C as an example).

Comment: Fair hunch @BigBen. Really I was hoping to get *close* to what OP was after with some examples of detecting sheet changes, determining if it was a change that they care about, testing to see what values are in the cells they care about, and then perform a hide/unhide on a row. We'll see what shakes out.

Comment: Re Q1 - I'd just note that it's always best to qualify ranges.  If the OP puts the code in the Worksheet's module, then using `Range("A1")` would necessarily refer to `Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")`.  If OP puts that code in the `ThisWorkbook` module, then using `Range("A1")` is ambiguous and would refer to `ActiveSheet.Range("A1")` and the activesheet may not necessarily be `Sheet2` and could cause issues/unexpected results.

Comment: There's SO many caveats here. OP, if I were you I would, for now, stay away from putting code in `ThisWorkbook` and instead stick to whichever Worksheet it is where you anticipate the event/action happening. Once you are comfortable there, then you can expand to `ThisWorkbook` where a change event could be for any worksheet in the workbook and you are prepared to deal with that extra scope.